# Is there any limit on size of a spark broadcast variable?

Tags: apache-spark, limit, broadcast

I am wondering if there is a limit size of a broadcast variable in spark because I need to broadcast a large object (6GB and can be larger in the future).
I have searched in the home page and this site but nothing was found to answer my question.
Would I ever have problems with broadcasting a very large object?

Comment: It is downloaded on every machine so you need memory for broadcast variable and all your tasks.

Comment: Did you mean the broadcast variable's size is limited only by the memory of each executor and we can have, for example, an 1TB broadcast variable if we have sufficient RAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit of Java Integer.MAX_VALUE. That is to say about 2,3 GB.
Please have a look here in Spark Jira for more information: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5739