# Spark Sreaming: broadcast variable size limit?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to use a [broadcast variable in Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables), and according to a previous question: [Is there any limit on size of a spark broadcast variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021419/is-there-any-limit-on-size-of-a-spark-broadcast-variable)
, the answer was that there is a limit of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which means 2-3 GB.

I need to broadcast a lookup table (lets say *HashMap* for example) to all mappers, and it may weight up to several GB (at least 2).

Is it possible or the limit size prevent me to implement it that way?

Comment: Do you *really* want to broadcast a variable 2GB in size? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to analyze a stream of events from a bunch of sensors. The analysis requires me to query some static lookup data, which is currently kept in a small database.

Comment: Have you thought about querying data on demand (lazily) and caching it locally in each worker?

Comment: Can you give an example?