# Spark: How to set the sc.broadcast maximum size

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to `sc.broadcast(val)`, the `val` maybe 100MB, my spark version is `2.3.2`. I find the job will be cancelled by itself if I pass `sc.broadcast(val)`.

I think it's because my `val` is large. So how to set maximum size of it?

Comment: Please see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045917/what-is-the-maximum-size-for-a-broadcast-object-in-spark

Comment: and this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021419/is-there-any-limit-on-size-of-a-spark-broadcast-variable

Comment: I see. Just use `spark.conf.set("spark.broadcast.blockSize", '100M')` on pyspark.